# Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.gwt.dev.GWTShell

Tags: java, android, gwt, libgdx

Alright, so I'm following a libgdx tutorial. Here is the tutorial in question: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WP5qA_kgV6Y&feature=c4-overview-vl&list=PL8E5pNjh8OR3f6X4tpjt0M0By6z0sB4MP

I just created a basic program with the gdx-setup-ui.jar file. I'm trying to run the html part as a web application when I get the following error:

Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.gwt.dev.GWTShell

I'm not sure what I failed to do, and I got very little help looking it up on google.

I did not change my code from the basic code that the gdx-setup-ui.jar file gives you, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I ran into this problem - it fixed itself after a few minutes... I didn't change anything. I think I tried to run the app too quickly after Eclipse booted up. Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to install Google's GWT extension into Eclipse.  See http://www.gwtproject.org/usingeclipse.html

Its listed as a [Prerequisite](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/Prerequisits) on the Libgdx wiki.  I thought it was mentioned more explicitly elsewhere, I can't find it ...

If you've got GWT installed, you may need to "fixup" the HTML projects:

> Open the "Problems" view. You should see several errors about "The
>   web.xml file does not exist". Just right-click on the error here, and
>   Quick Fix it. You'll get a dialog for which you just need to click
>   Finish.

Comment: Are you certain that's what I want? My eclipse is Kepler(4.3), and when I go to Download Plugin & SDKs from the main page > Download, it gives me a completely separate page: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download

Comment: GWT is (was?) a Google project, but it looks like they've recently moved to some more external website (I got that link from the Libgdx wiki).  However you do it, you'll need to get GWT installed before the Libgdx HTML backend is going to work.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Window>Preferences>Google>Web Toolkit>` and select the proper `sdk`.

Then go to `Window>Preferences>Google>App Engine>` and select the proper `sdk`.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely the Web Application Main class is wrong.

First verify that Properties | Google | Web Application | This project has a WAR directory is checked and the path is correct.

Second open the Run Configurations Web Application dialog.
On the main tab, replace com.google.gwt.dev.GWTShell with com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode
You may also need to verify the parameters within the Arguments tab.